# Ethernet disconnects sporadically

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, 23.10

After updating from 23.04 to 23.10, my ethernet cuts out several times a day for 3-10 minutes.  I have replaced cables, checked my eero, router and switch (all other machines on the same network work fine).

I am not very experienced in this area, but did run `journlctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` and noticed the following:

```
nm-device: NM-e507e71e-69ca-45a0-a29b-9bca903eade7: the renderer for nm-devices must be NetworkManager, it will be used instead of the default
```

I am not sure if this is connected or not.
Any suggestions on where I should start troubleshooting?

Result of cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    NM-572e2b55-138a-4fb3-9613-d4215cc6eae2:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "eno1"
        macaddress: "B8:CA:3A:95:3B:3A"
      addresses:
      - "192.168.4.142/22"
      dhcp6: true
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      wakeonlan: true
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "572e2b55-138a-4fb3-9613-d4215cc6eae2"
        name: "Profile 1"
        passthrough:
          connection.timestamp: "1704726021"
          ipv4.address1: "192.168.4.142/22,192.168.4.1"
          ipv4.method: "manual"
          ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
          proxy._: ""
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    NM-7d2232bb-ad38-4422-b841-e5076c127be2:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "eno1"
        macaddress: "B8:CA:3A:95:3B:3A"
      addresses:
      - "192.168.4.142/22"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      wakeonlan: true
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "7d2232bb-ad38-4422-b841-e5076c127be2"
        name: "eno1"
        passthrough:
          connection.autoconnect: "false"
          connection.timestamp: "1706110387"
          ipv4.address1: "192.168.4.142/24,192.168.4.1"
          ipv4.method: "manual"
          ipv6.method: "ignore"
          proxy._: ""
```

Comment: "the renderer for nm-devices must be NetworkManager" Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`